# Control template trigger not firing correctly after property change in code behind [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a periodic table of elements wpf application and have made my buttons like this:

```
<!-- RoundedButton.xaml -->
```

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="4" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="RoundedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Name="butt">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">


                <Border CornerRadius="12,12,12,12" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>

                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="12,12,12,12"  x:Name="bordertrue">
                        <Grid>

                            <Border Opacity="0" x:Name="Shine" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" CornerRadius="12,12,10,10" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="Indigo" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Crimson" Offset="0.5"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Crimson" Offset="0.5"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Indigo" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.5"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="border">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Shine" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Gold"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Gold" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="ExtraBold"/>

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is working perfectly on mouseover. However in my app I have a combination of textbox and listbox which makes me a searchbox. Whenever I search for a particular element I wish to make the same "Shine button" effect as on mouseover in style above

I've tried to do it like this:

```
private void highlight(string elementName, bool MultiOrSingle)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush gradient1 = new LinearGradientBrush();
        gradient1.StartPoint = new Point(0.5, 0);
        gradient1.EndPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);

        gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Indigo, 0));
        gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Crimson, 0.5));
        gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Crimson, 0.5));
        gradient1.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Indigo, 1));
        if (MultiOrSingle == true)
        {
            foreach (Button elementButton in VisualChildren.FindVisualChildren<Button>(this))
            {
                if (listBox.Items.Contains(elementButton.Name) == true)
                {
                    elementButton.Background = gradient1;
                    elementButton.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                    elementButton.Foreground = Brushes.Gold;
                    elementButton.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gold;
                }
                else
                {
                    elementButton.Background = previousBackgroundColors[elementButton.Name];
                    elementButton.Foreground = previousForegroundColors[elementButton.Name];
                }
            }
            foreach (Button elementButton in VisualChildren.FindVisualChildren<Button>(this))
            {
                if (elementButton.Name != "play_quiz" &&
                    elementButton.Name != "show_scoreboard" &&
                    elementButton.Name != "update" &&
                    elementButton.Name != "DragDropGames" &&
                    listBox.Items.Contains(elementButton.Name) == false)
                {
                    elementButton.Background = Brushes.Gainsboro;
                    elementButton.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkBlue;
                    elementButton.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                    elementButton.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Button elementButton in VisualChildren.FindVisualChildren<Button>(this))
            {
                if (elementName == elementButton.Name)
                {

                    elementButton.Background = gradient1;
                    elementButton.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gold;
                    elementButton.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                    elementButton.Foreground = Brushes.Gold;
                }
                else
                {
                    elementButton.Background = previousBackgroundColors[elementButton.Name];
                    elementButton.Foreground = previousForegroundColors[elementButton.Name];
                }
            }

            foreach (Button elementButton in VisualChildren.FindVisualChildren<Button>(this))
            {
                if (elementButton.Name != "play_quiz" &&
                    elementButton.Name != "show_scoreboard" &&
                    elementButton.Name != "update" &&
                    elementButton.Name != "DragDropGames" &&
                    elementName != elementButton.Name)
                {
                    elementButton.Background = Brushes.Gainsboro;
                    elementButton.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkBlue;
                    elementButton.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                    elementButton.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
                }
            }
        }
```

with just setting backgrounds brushes etc etc....

However I encountered 2 problems. When doing this in code behind i can change everything but my border brush will remain as it is determined in xaml style I can't change it in code behind don't know why? And after calling this function when I mouse over the buttons they will Shine...however property foreground won't be changed to gold? It will remain black

to demonstrate :

[So this is my mouseover "Shine". When I go with mouse over the button it will change it's look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EHIr.jpg)

[So this is my problem I have searched for H..it came back with few results and called function from above as "multi" and selected all results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgzVq.jpg)

However this didn't work "elementButton.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gold" it remained transparent as in xaml. And suddenly my Mouseover shine is not the same anymore it's 
`<Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Gold" />
<Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="ExtraBold"/>`

don't seem to be triggering after the function call

To sum it up. I would like to have the same look of the button and shine effect for all my textbox searches

Answer (score 2):

Your `Trigger` changes the `BorderBrush` on element named "`Border`". However in your code behind you are setting the `BorderBrush` on the button, which does nothing because you don't use the property `BorderBrush` anywhere in your template. What you need to do is `TemplateBinding` the Button's `BorderBrush` property to the template, like the following:

```
<Border CornerRadius="12,12,12,12" 
        BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
        x:Name="border" 
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
```

In order to get the `FontWeight` and `Foreground` to trigger when the mouse is over the button when properties is set in code behind, one possible solution is the following.

Set the `TextBlock` property in the `ContentPresenter` and then use `TemplateBinding` to set the value.

```
<ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                  TextBlock.FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                  Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  x:Name="contentPresenter"/>

<Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="White" />
<Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="ExtraBold"/>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, one thing remains though. Why my foreground and background are not changing after changing them in code behind?

Comment: Updated the solution to include the changing after changing them in code behind.